# 16.04 Usb Wifi adapter won't connect on reboot until physically removed and reinserted

Tags: wireless, usb

Realtek 8192 300Mbps 802.11n/g/bs adapter. Always sees networks but won't connect unless physically removed from the usb slot and reinserted, then connects perfectly fine and stays connected until a reboot. Can't figure it out.

edit with info

```
uname -r  
4.10.0-40-generic  

lsusb  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver  
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 0bda:818b Realtek Semiconductor Corp.   
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0a81:0101 Chesen Electronics Corp. Keyboard  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  

lsmod | grep rtl  
rtl8xxxu              126976  0  
mac80211              782336  1 rtl8xxxu  

sudo lshw -C network 
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (2) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 31
       serial: 70:85:c2:5d:17:25
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.8-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:135 memory:f7f00000-f7f1ffff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:2
       logical name: wlxe84e064fde7a
       serial: e8:4e:06:4f:de:7a
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8xxxu driverversion=4.10.0-40-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.14 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of these terminal commands: `uname -r` and also: `lsusb` and also: `lsmod | grep rtl` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: And `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: added relevant info